# How can I send my dialogflow chat history to my admin panel ?( As it an ordering app , sorted data should be sent to admin panel)

Tags: dialogflow-es, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

As it my ordering app , orders should be sorted and sent to admin panel or just I shall be able to retrieve order from  bots chat history . **How to retrieve chat or an order list and Name ,address, etc from google dialogflow and send to admin panel or a database**

Answer (score 2):

I dont think it is possible to download the History, you can enable 'Log interactions to Google Cloud' in the Settings, then you can acces (also download) the events that occur during the conversation.

The best option is however to build a Webhook, so all user interactions are sent to your backend where you can store data into DB or apply some custom logic.

Comment: Sir I am new to this could you please help me for building a webhook so all user interactions are sent to our backend where we can store data into DB or apply some custom logic.                                                                                                     Thanks in Advance

Comment: Probably best starting point is to look at creating Inline webhook https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/tutorials/build-an-agent/create-fulfillment-using-webhook

Alternatively look for DialogFlow Webhook Tutorials with Python if you want to build/deploy your backend (webhook) on your server or cloud (instead of using Google)